# How to run the code in an __init__.py

Tags: python

I have found some code that I think will allow me to communicate with my Helios Heat recovery unit.  I am relatively new to Python (but not coding in general) and I really cannot work out how to use this code.  It is obviously written for smarthome.py but I'd like to use it from the command line.

I can also see that the way this file is constructed is probably not the best way to construct an __init__.py but I'd like to try and use it first.

So, how do I run this code? https://github.com/mtiews/smarthomepy-helios

Cheers

Comment: You typically don't run the init file. It gets executed when you import the module

Comment: It's a plugin for another module... you don't run it directly... read the readme...

Comment: Yes I realise it is a plugin and that normally you would not run the init file directly (as I said).  I just did not want to install what it plugged into and was not sure how to run it directly.  The readme does suggest it can be used from the command line.  I was just not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `git clone https://github.com/mtiews/smarthomepy-helios.git`: either

- invoke python with the `__init__.py` script as argument:

  ```sh
  python smarthomepy-helios/__init__.py
  ```

  or
- make the `__init__.py` executable and run it:

  ```sh
  chmod u+x smarthomepy-helios/__init__.py
  smarthomepy-helios/__init__.py
  ```

Running it either way gives me

> 2016-02-20 18:07:51,791 - root - ERROR - Helios: Could not open /dev/ttyUSB0.
>   Exception: Not connected

But passing `--help` I get some nice synopsis:

```
$> python smarthomepy-helios/__init__.py --help
usage: __init__.py [-h] [-t PORT] [-r READ_VAR] [-w WRITE_VAR] [-v VALUE] [-d]

Helios ventilation system commandline interface.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -t PORT, --tty PORT   Serial device to use
  -r READ_VAR, --read READ_VAR
                        Read variables from ventilation system
  -w WRITE_VAR, --write WRITE_VAR
                        Write variable to ventilation system
  -v VALUE, --value VALUE
                        Value to write (required with option -v)
  -d, --debug           Prints debug statements.

Without arguments all readable values using default tty will be retrieved.
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Just what I needed.  Had to install pyserial with pip but works a treat.